# Arrangements for two letters such that one of them does not appear consecutively

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume I have 4 “As” and 8 “B”s. How many strings of length 12 are there? How many strings of length 12 have no 2 “A”s adjacent?

I have been able to do the first part quite easily by finding 12!/4!8! but I am unable to do the next part - could anyone please help?

Comment: Ah! Thanks for catching that - it was a typo, all edited now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of arrangements of $4$ A's and $8$ B's with no two A's adjacent is the same as the number of arrangements of $4$ A's and $9$ B's with every A immediately followed by a B, which is the same as the number of arrangements of $4$ AB's and $5$ B's, so the answer is $\binom94=\frac{9!}{4!5!}=126$.

Comment: Thanks @bof, that's honestly super helpful. May I ask why you wrote 9Bs?

Comment: Because I wanted to turn in into a problem about *unrestricted* arrangements of A's and AB's. In a string of 4 A's and 8 B's with no consecutive A's, it's not sure that each A is immediately followed by a B, because the **last** letter could be an A. Adding a B at the right end of the string fixes this problem. Adding a B on the right converts any string of 4 As and 8 Bs with no consecutive A's into a string of 4 As and 9 Bs with each A followed by a B.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for that. All sorted and it makes complete sense :)